# Error while using bitcore library for generating public addresses

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, bitcore

When i try to import bitcore generated address it gives -5 error i,e. invalid multichain address or script. I don't understand why i am getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

Have you created the address in the bitcoin format? Multichain uses a different format for generating addresses. You wouldn't be able to import a bitcoin type address into multichain unless you create the chain with the bitcoin format.

Kindly checkout https://www.multichain.com/developers/address-key-format/

Comment: Okay,  so this is because of the parameters that are changed by multichain. They made changes in the parameters like address checksum, pubkeyhash version, privatekey version. So, I have to adjust it according to Bitcoin one so that it could support bitcore functionality. Is it the case?

Comment: Yes, that's true. @trinayan